# Any way to figure out if Word Document is protected with NoReset flag

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, word-interop

the word api (interop and vba) allow to call `Document.Protect([...],NoReset,[...])` with a `NoReset` flag. Is there any way to find out if this flag is set by a protected document? I look into OpenXML specification and compare two documents which have the same structure but protected with enabled/disabled flag.

**Problem**

The problem behind is that i call `ActiveDocument.Fields.Update()` in my code for documents which are not protected by myself. When i do it and the flag is not set the `FormField.Result` values will be reset to the `FormField.TextInput.Default` value and this i will prevent.

So the question is how can i find out before i call `Update()` if this flag is set or not.

**Knowledge**

What i find out now is that there is actual no property in the object model which i can call to check if the property is set. The OpenXML specification has also no flag on top the formfield xml specification.The only differences i see in comparison of this, is that Word also added revision id`s to the xml.

Maybe someone has a little bit more informations and can help.

Best regards
Daniel

Comment: There is no 'NoReset' property stored in the document. All that  'NoReset' does is to tell Word whether to reset formfields to their default values when applying 'filling in forms' protection. You can instead use ActiveDocument.ProtectionType to test whether - and what kind - of protection a document has. You might get better results by telling Word to do a .PrintPreview and .ClosePrintPreview on the document.

Comment: But how can Word decide that `Application.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update` should be reset the FormField.Result to the default values? I compare both document before and after reset to the defaults values. It seems to be that the RSID tracking ids changed to other values but not more.

Comment: Ah `NoReset` is only works at runtime if `Document.Protect` is calling. I understand. Then i have a different problem. I believed that the reset behavior of old formfields is a result of protecting documents and the `NoReset` flag and this is false.

Comment: Okay ist seems to be that default behaviour which Word implements is depend on the ProtectionType. If no protection is set the behaviour of formfields is that everytime when `Application.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update` is called the formfields are reset the current `.Result` value to the `.Default` value

Comment: « If no protection is set the behaviour of formfields is that everytime when Application.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update is called the formfields are reset the current .Result value to the .Default value» Correct. So why are you using formfields?

Comment: This is not a decision myself to use form fields but i must handle it

Comment: @macropod Thank you for your input which helped to understand this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the solution for this problem (see comments) is to understand first that there a two problems.

**First problem:**

`NoReset` flag is only evaluated at runtime if `Document.Protect` is called.

**secound problem:**

If the document is unprotected word`s standard behaviour is to reset `FormFields` if `Fields.Update` is called. To avoid this you can enumerate the `Field` collection and check if `Field.Type` is not `wdFieldFormTextInput` and call than `Field.Update`

Comment: Alternatively, protect the document for forms - with NoReset = True - then update fields before unprotecting the document again.

Comment: Yeah that is right and another solution.